# Phalcon ORM: How to get all records with relations

Tags: php, mysql, orm, phalcon

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach ($user->usersGroups as $usersGroupsRelation) {
   echo $usersGroupsRelation->group->name .'<br>';
};
```

I this example i found one main record and all related records. But what should i do to get all main records with all relations ? (Without getting related records into the loop for every main record).

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give us an example of the result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lovely read with a lot of opinions here: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1117

You could use Andres suggestion for reusable model relations in this comment "andresgutierrez commented on Aug 10, 2015" or even cache the whole resultset.

```
class Robots extends Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "RobotsParts", "robots_id",
        [
            "alias" => "parts",
            "reusable" => true
        ]);
    }
}
```